# How to integrate Angular 7 application in Springboot Jar?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, gradle, angular7

I want to integrate my front end Angular 7 application which is accessible via http://localhost:4200/ in spring boot jar so that after integration with spring boot Angular 7 application will be accessible through spring boot port via url http://localhost:8081/

I want to integrate angular in spring boot jar itself so that angular application would be accessible when I will run java -jar App.jar

I am using gradle for building spring boot jar.

Comment: see chapter 2 of this course: https://www.udemy.com/angular-4-java-developers/

Comment: Will it work with Angular 7?

Comment: The principle remains similar.

Comment: You can use jhipster . Its even better

Comment: Are you also concerned by the way to build it ? or only do you only want to make it work with spring ?

All resources in resources/static will be served by Spring

Answer (score 1):

Add a build step to your maven/gradle to build Angular app by invoking `ng build`, then copy generated files from your Angular app's `dist` folder into Java resources. If you're using gradle, this step should be executed before `processResources`. If using maven, I have no clue, I haven't used maven in centuries, sorry.

Another options is to create a npm task which will do the same before you run your java build.

Comment: I have added Angular app's dist folder in Java resources still application is not accessible